# CSS Flexbox image scale inside child

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions, css-transforms

> I have the following html :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>asd</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide3"></div>
      <div class="slide slide4"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> and the following css :

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

.slide1 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Fantastic-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide2 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Galaxy-Space-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide3 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Landscape-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide4 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Free-Desktop-Background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index:20;
}
```

The zoom inside the div flex seems like a minor glitch on transform `scale` 
and i also want to find a way to just zoom the background image inside the div and not the div (that will be scaled outside of the view-port).

I tried adding a parent wrapper but it scales the div and not the background image .

As you can see in this Codepen :
https://codepen.io/pufosme/pen/MZWWpM

*Thank you !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below. I wrapped the `slide`s with a parent container and added `overflow: hidden`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

.slide1 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Fantastic-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide2 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Galaxy-Space-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide3 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Landscape-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide4 {
  background-image: url('http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Free-Desktop-Background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="slide slide1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="slide slide2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="slide slide3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="slide slide4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why width: 400px ?

Comment: i change with `flex:1`  so  that even after insertion a new image, they are all equally wide be stays.

Comment: i saw now but i still dont get why it's working with flex : 1 :) and also i think you should use `-webkit-flex: 1;` and `-ms-flex: 1;`

Comment: this is extra so i will need a hint . i will want in the future to add an event , on a click on that div , to expand fully like sliding left - right from where it is to the full width of the browser . any tip ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use an IMG inside each slide (using object-fit and object-position to replace the background properties). Then scale the image and not the slide and, on each slide, you set `overflow: hidden`.

Like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOGNoN

```
.slide {
  ...
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

.slide:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index:20;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rg-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="slide slide1">
  <img src='http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Fantastic-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg' />
</div>
```

Comment: @DogukanCavus just tried it an it works, no idea why it does not open for you.

Comment: i confirm codepen is working . this is really nice , but object-fit and object-position are crossbrowser support ?

Comment: W3school says `object-fit` and `object-position` works on all modern browsers. MDN says `object-position` doesn't work on safari, no idea if w3school lies or if MDN is outdated haha.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=object-position says both works on all modern browsers. EDIT: sorry, caniuse says the same as MDN, that safari doesn't support object-position